# Any way to improve AD performance over a VPN?

Tags: active-directory, vpn

I have a distributed Network, with a SharePoint server located in a remote office that is part of company domain via VPN.

When the Sharepoint server queries anything AD related performance isn't ideal.

Can I do anything about this? Somehow configure AD for better handling over VPN? Or possibly setup a 2nd DC on the remote side that can sync with primary DC and have Sharepoint query secondary?

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install a DC at the remote site.
2. Set up ADS&S for both sites/subnets.
3. Configure the Sharepoint server and clients at the remote site to use the remote site DC for primary DNS.

Comment: Will objects automatically sync? Users, Org Units, etc?

Comment: Yes they will...